# Bluetooth keyboard not working after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

After the update my bluetooth keyboard works fine with the exception of the **Shift**, **Ctrl**, **Alt**, and **win/start** keys (oddly the menu key works).

Running `xev` shows that no event is generated on a keypress.  Switching to a wired keyboard works and the keys work which leads me to believe its a bluetooth issue.

I killed and restarted bluetooth and the issue still persists.  Even the volume buttons work on it, but not those buttons which I obviously need.  Is this a bluetooth issue from the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

My bluetooth mouse stopped working after the upgrade, it keeps telling me that it is requesting access. I grant it but the pointer stands still. I think the problem is related.

Booting with the old 3.2 kernel makes it work, so I think it's a kernel issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround, it worked for my mouse:

- Turn off your keyboard
- Make the computer forget about the bluetooth device
- Boot with the old kernel
- Turn on and pair your keyboard, see if it works OK. If not, this doesn't work for you. If it works:
- Restart and boot with the new kernel.

I restarted a lot of times before switching kernels, and there was no change. When booted with the old kernel, it started working. Now I can boot with any kernel I want, it works. Strange, but see if it works for you.